# MATLAB lsqcurvefit with a gaussian convolution model

Tags: matlab, distribution, curve-fitting, gaussian

I am trying to fit data that is described by a Gaussian distribution of convoluted exponential. An example of some perfect simulated data to illustrate my point:

```
clc; clear all

modeValue = 40;          % mode value of our simulated gaussian
sig = 4;                 % variance
values = [1:0.5:100];    % vector for gaussian to be evaluated at

gauss=(1/(sqrt(2*pi)*sig)).*exp(-(values-modeValue).^2/(2*sig^2))'; % create our gaussian
gauss=gauss./max(gauss); % normalize

tau = logspace(-6,2,256); % generate our simulated x-data

for ii = 1:1:length(values)
data(:,ii) = exp(-tau.*values(ii)); % generated a data set
end

dataConv = data*gauss; % Multiply each data set by the corresponding gaussian weight
dataConv = dataConv./max(dataConv); % This is our final simulated data
semilogx(tau,dataConv,'ro');
```

If this code is run in `MATLAB`, a perfect generated data set `dataConv` is created.

My goal now is to recover our `gauss` plot by doing a `lsqcurvefit` on our generated data. The idea is to give a starting value for `modeValue`, `sig` and `values`, and have `MATLAB` automatically select them, generated all of the decay curves, convolute all the decays into 1 data set, check the fit, then go back and tweak the input values.

I can fit a single exponential using `lsqcurvefit`, but don't see how to do what I am after. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you going to recover `modeValue` and `sig` from some input data?

Comment: Yes, but in this example the input data is `dataConv`.